# XSLT 1.0 - external file lookup table

Tags: xml, perl, xslt

I am using Perl and the CPAN module [XML::LibXSLT](http://search.cpan.org/~shlomif/XML-LibXSLT-1.96/LibXSLT.pm) to perform XML transformations (thus restricted to XSLT version 1.0). I am completely new to XSLT transformations, but I find it interesting and potentially very powerful. I want to convert a number into another using an external file for lookup, but so far I'm unable to get the desired results:

```
D:\>perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use XML::LibXSLT;
use XML::LibXML;
my $xslt = XML::LibXSLT->new();
my $source = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => 'invoice.xml');
my $style_doc = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location=>'akv2abz.xsl', no_cdata=>1);
my $stylesheet = $xslt->parse_stylesheet($style_doc);
my $results = $stylesheet->transform($source);
print $stylesheet->output_as_bytes($results);
__END__
compilation error: file akv2abz.xsl element stylesheet
xsl:version: only 1.0 features are supported
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Invoice>
  <AdditionalDocumentReference>
    <DocumentType>ABZ</DocumentType>
    <ID/>
  </AdditionalDocumentReference>
</Invoice>
```

Expected output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Invoice>
  <AdditionalDocumentReference>
    <DocumentType>ABZ</DocumentType>
    <ID>ABC123</ID>
  </AdditionalDocumentReference>
</Invoice>
```

The lookup file:

```
D:\>type lookup.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<QueryResult>
  <Result>
    <ac_name>80186780</ac_name>
    <obj_license>ABC123</obj_license>
  </Result>
  <Result>
    <ac_name>60521933</ac_name>
    <obj_license>DEF567</obj_license>
  </Result>
  <Result>
    <ac_name>60606508</ac_name>
    <obj_license>GHI890</obj_license>
  </Result>
</QueryResult>
```

The source document:

```
D:\>type invoice.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Invoice>
    <AdditionalDocumentReference>
        <ID>80186780</ID>
        <DocumentType>AKV</DocumentType>
    </AdditionalDocumentReference>
</Invoice>

D:\>
```

The stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name='QueryResult' select='document("lookup.xml")/Result'/>
    <xsl:template match='Invoice'>
        <Invoice>
            <xsl:apply-templates select='AdditionalDocumentReference'/>
        </Invoice>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- By default, copy everything -->
    <xsl:template match="*|@*|text()|/">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*|@*|text()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- AdditionalDocumentReference with documentType=AKV should be replaced 
        with AdditionalDocumentReference DocumentType=ABZ and the ID should 
        replaced with the correct obj_license --> 
    <xsl:template match="AdditionalDocumentReference[DocumentType='AKV']"> 
        <xsl:copy>
            <DocumentType>ABZ</DocumentType>
            <ID><xsl:value-of select='$QueryResult[@ac_name=current( )/ID]/@obj_license'/></ID>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Am I on to something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use XSLT 1 (and your stylesheet doesn't use any XSLT 2 features) then use `version="1.0"` on the `xsl:stylesheet` or `xsl:transform` root element of the XSLT code as I think libxslt otherwise refuses to run the code.

Additionally if you want to select elements and not attributes you need paths like `ac_name` and not `@ac_name` so correct

```
<xsl:value-of select='$QueryResult[@ac_name=current( )/ID]/@obj_license'/>
```

to

```
<xsl:value-of select='$QueryResult[ac_name=current( )/ID]/obj_license'/>
```

And another path is also wrong, the complete stylesheet with all corrections is

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name='QueryResult' select='document("test2018050202.xml")/QueryResult/Result'/>
    <xsl:template match='Invoice'>
        <Invoice>
            <xsl:apply-templates select='AdditionalDocumentReference'/>
        </Invoice>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- By default, copy everything -->
    <xsl:template match="*|@*|text()|/">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*|@*|text()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- AdditionalDocumentReference with documentType=AKV should be replaced 
        with AdditionalDocumentReference DocumentType=ABZ and the ID should 
        replaced with the correct obj_license --> 
    <xsl:template match="AdditionalDocumentReference[DocumentType='AKV']"> 
        <xsl:copy>
            <DocumentType>ABZ</DocumentType>
            <ID><xsl:value-of select='$QueryResult[ac_name = current()/ID]/obj_license'/></ID>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I did the change but it still does not produce the desired output (same as before). Is that because this is a XSLT "2.0" solution and I am using an XSLT "1.0" tool?

Comment: @AndreasF if you removed all mentions of version 2.0 you should not get an error message that refers to version 2.0. Are you sure you changed the correct template file? Is there some other template involved that you are missing?

Comment: So you have changed the version to `1.0` but still get that error `only 1.0 features are supported`? I would first try to run the code outside of Perl with xsltproc to check it is working, then you can try using Perl to execute the XSLT. Using relative URLs like `document("lookup.xml")` is obviously only possible if the base URI is available, I don't know whether `XML::LibXML->load_xml` manages that. But that shouldn't give that error about the version features.

Comment: I was imprecise: The error message from XML::LibXSLT "only 1.0 features are supported" is gone, but the XML output is the same:

Comment: See the edit, there was another path not selecting the input structure from your samples, now corrected.

Answer (score 2):

There are several different versions of XSLT. Your stylesheet is of the version 2 flavor,

> ```
> <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
> ```

but the Perl module you are using to apply the XSLT stylesheet does not support that.

> ```
> xsl:version: only 1.0 features are supported
> ```

It looks like you do know that already though.

Comment: Additionally `<xsl:value-of select='$QueryResult[@ac_name=current( )/ID]/@obj_license'/>` should be `<xsl:value-of select='$QueryResult[ac_name=current( )/ID]/obj_license'/>` as there elements like `ac_name` in the input and not attributes.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I don't remember enough XSLT to verify that without research. I trust you're right, but I'm not going to edit it into my answer, as that's about something else really. If you know a way to turn OP's template into version 1, please post your own answer. :)